# ¿Cómo localizar los archivos mas recientes de cada carpeta de un árbol de carpetas en Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystem

Tengo un árbol de directorios que recorrer en linux, cada uno de esos directorios tiene un número muy grande de archivos y en esencia lo que necesito es la salida como la suele dar el comando `ls` pero sólo del último archivo de cada una de las carpetas.

No me sirve comparar con la hora del sistema, pues se puede dar el caso de que sean archivos más viejos y sin embargo haya sido el de más reciente creación para un directorio particular.

Hasta el momento he probado con `ls -t /home/user/Documents/*/*.*`pero eso me imprime todos los archivos.

¿Existe alguna forma de limitar ese comportamiento?

Answer (score 4):

- Con: `ls -lt` ordenas los archivos del directorio donde estés por la fecha de creación. Bueno, la fecha en que se tocaron por ultima vez.
- Con `ls -ltr` los ordenas al revés de la fecha de creacion o modificacion.
- Con `ls -lh`los ordenas por tamaño...

Siempre te queda el comando `help` o `man ls` para investigar

En  `echo $PATH` tienes todos los comandos ejecutables.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que comentas, ya conoces `ls` y todas sus opciones. Sin embargo, necesitas hacer algo así como "ls -ltr" en cada uno de ellos.

Pues bueno, hazlo :)

```
for dir in /home/user/Documents/*/*;
do
   echo "$dir"
   ls -ltr "$dir" | tail -n 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Con awk puedes formatear el resultado de ls y mostrar solo el primer archivo más reciente de cada directorio

```
ls -t1 /home/user/Documents/*/*.* | awk -f a.awk
```

a.awk es el nombre de archivo del script, he intentado tener en cuenta los archivos que pudiesen estar en el directorio más elevado por si fuesen requeridos, en resumen lo que hace es procesar linea a linea hasta encontrar un directorio que acaban en ":" e imprime el directorio y la linea siguiente que correspondería al archivo más nuevo.
Tenia morriña de awk, espero que te sirva.

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    nuevoDirectorio = false;
    lDir = 0;
}
{
    if (NR == 1 && $0 !~ /:$/) {
        # si existen ficheros en el directorio superior
        print ".";
        print $0;
    } else if ($0 ~ /:$/) {
        lDir=NR;
        nuevoDirectorio = true;
        print $0;
    } else if (nuevoDirectorio == true && NR==lDir+1) {
        # si se usa ls -l se saltarán +2 lineas
        print $0;
        nuevoDirectorio = false;    
    }
}
END {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma para navegar un tree y ver que archivos son los "mas nuevos"
en el ejemplo `./app` es el punto de partida

```
find ./app -type d -printf "ls -ldtr %p/* .* | egrep -v "^d.*" | tail -n 1; " | sh
```

**Notas**

- `find ./app -type d -printf " ... "` busca solo carpetas y arma una cadena de texto (un comando shell) que luego le pasa al `| sh` del final
- `ls -ldtr %p/* .*` omite el texto `total ...`, muestra detalles (para saber el path) y ordena por time en reversa
- `egrep -v "^d.*"` omite carpetas (el mask de permisos empieza con d)